# Windows 10 Mouse Randomly Stops Working

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, cursor

having an issue with a new PC whereby the mouse randomly stops working.

When it stops working it has the following:

- Cursor shows on screen.
- Mouse laser/light still on.

However it cannot move or allow clicks.

I have tested the following to no avail:

- Uninstalled driver (So using basic mouse driver)
- Reinstalled driver (via windows updates)
- Tried 3 other mice (hardware)
- Tried all USB ports (inc USB3 ports)

The only solution I can find to fix it is giving the PC a reboot, then comes back to life.

Also when swapping mice I can see Windows 10 installing it/configuring due to the notifications. But afterwards I get the same, no movement or clicks just light and cursor on screen.

Any help much appreciated, feel stupid I can't fix a basic mouse issue!!

Comment: Have you tried a registry cleaner?  You may also want to type into the Microsoft Help "mouse stops working randomly".  This gives several solutions to try.  You may want to try to reinstall your mouse drivers as well.

Comment: Check out this forum.  Not sure what solution would work for you but it gives you ideas of what to try.
https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20744864488

Comment: Is it possible that it's actually the mouse's fault?

Comment: @Dale Registry cleaners are a bad idea.

Comment: Why are they a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try these fixes.

1 - Disable VSync, this did not work for me but may work for you

2 - Plug into a USB 2.0 port (my fix) I noticed it was happening in Windows as well, I have not encountered the issue since then. Its funny cause I was using USB 3.0 and then noticed my motherboard has USB ports labeled "gaming USB ports" - Using these fixed the problem, I believe they are just USB 2.0 ports but I have not had an issue since I plugged into these.

3 - Update your BIOS and mouse drivers this could fix the USB 3.0 issue all together but it is most likely one of these things or a combination of the two.

4 - Check your windows event LOG (anything with errors in there under "System" should be addressed if they are time stamped while you are playing. Use the googles to find out how to fix them.

Comment: Switching from a USB 2 to a USB 3 port solved my problem, after reading your suggestions. Disabling power saving options in Device Manager and Power Plan made no difference to the USB 2 ports.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with my Bluetooth-connected MX Anywhere 2 mouse. I managed to find that the built-in Bluetooth troubleshooter was the only fix.

[image: Start menu entry for 'Find and fix problems with Bluetooth devices']

[image: Find and fix problems with Bluetooth devices window]

I used @Sysinternals Process Explorer to identify the full command line arguments as follows:

```
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\msdt.exe"  -id BluetoothDiagnostic -ep CortanaSearch -elevated yes
```

This means you can create a shortcut to the troubleshooter using the above command as the

[image: right click to create a new shortcut]

[image]